# How to show an article's writer in View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build a blog site using Asp.Net MVC.

There are a lot of models, but I simplified them in my question. My article model as follow

Article class:

```
public class Article {
public int ArticleID { get; set; }
public String Content { get; set; }
public int? LoginID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("LoginID")]
public virtual LoginUser LoginUser { get; set; }
```

LoginUser class:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public String Name { get; set; }
public String Surname { get; set; }
...
```

I would want to view an article's writer in a .cshtml page. Tried the following code but failed.

```
@Model.LoginUser.Name
```

How can I show the name and surname which belong to article?

Comment: Can you show us the entire .cshtml?

Comment: What do you mean "failed"? Did you make sure your model was properly populated by your controller? Did the name appear in the HTML markup? What happened?

Comment: ```@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LoginUser.Name)```

Comment: I got "System.NullReferenceException". When I try @PauloCampez 's method, blank appeared in view.

Comment: Please show the controller method that renders this view, including any code that populates the Article and User. Also please show the model declaration at the top of the view page. Thanks.